# How to disable mouse interactions in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

Windows Terminal has a strange relationship with the mouse that I don't understand, and that I want to disable:

- right-clicking to paste text will instead copy garbled characters in the command prompt
- in `vim` rather than pasting it will switch me to "(insert) VISUAL" mode.
- When using `tmux` panes I won't be able to select text from a different pane.

How can I disable all these settings so that the mouse doesn't interact with the unix programs and cause eratic behaviour? Basically I want Windows Terminal to behave like putty as far as the mouse is concerned (I just want to use the mouse to select text and right-click to paste).

**EDIT**: I've noticed that I can achieve the desired behaviour by holding down shift while dragging to select text in the terminal. This has the desired effect. How can I make it so it always behaves like this, rather than having to press shift?

Answer (score 1):

So I actually had the same problem with the Windows Terminal and its weird interaction with tmux. Turns out that tmux itself had to have mouse-mode enabled in order for it to work properly with panes (`C-b + m`).

As for vim, I'm not sure what the problem is: left-clicking will select and copy, and right-clicking will put you into INSERT mode and paste (if you're in a tmux session, Shift + right-click is your best bet).

My WinTerminal has these options in regards to the mouse:

```json
// If enabled, selections are automatically copied to your clipboard.
"copyOnSelect": false,
// If enabled, formatted data is also copied to your clipboard
"copyFormatting": false,
```